# how to periodically update native c++ function

Tags: dart

inside the native sample_extension example I added a function to get the current active window title.
Inside dart I want to periodically call and print the getActivetWindowTitle

```
import "sample_extension.dart";
import "dart:async";

void main() {
  var isLittleEndian = SysInfo.isLittleEndian;
  var pageSize = SysInfo.pageSize;
  var sizeOfInt = SysInfo.sizeOfInt;
  var version = SysInfo.version;

  print('Dart VM (${sizeOfInt * 8} bit): $version');
  print('Page size: $pageSize KB');
  print('Endianness: ${isLittleEndian ? 'Little-endian' : 'Big-endian'}');


  new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds:1), (timer) => pr() );

}

void pr(){
  var activeWindow = SysInfo.activeWindow;
  print('Active window: $activeWindow');
}
```

my dart file sample_extension.dart is

```
library sample_extension;

import "dart-ext:sample_extension";

class SysInfo {
  //<se>
  static bool isLittleEndian = _isLittleEndian();
  static final int pageSize = _getPageSize();
  static final int sizeOfInt = _getSizeOfInt();
  static final String version = _getVersionString();

  static bool _isLittleEndian() native "IsLittleEndian";
  static int _getPageSize() native "GetPageSize";
  static int _getSizeOfInt() native "GetSizeOfInt";
  static String _getVersionString() native "GetVersionString";
  //</se>
  //<aui>
  static final String activeWindow = _getActiveWindowString();
  static String _getActiveWindowString() native "GetActiveWindowString";
  //</aui>
}
```

additional cc part is

```
void GetActiveWindowString(Dart_NativeArguments arguments) {
  Dart_Handle result;
  HWND hwnd;
  LPTSTR lpString;

  Dart_EnterScope();
  hwnd=GetForegroundWindow(); 
  GetWindowText(hwnd, lpString, 128);
  result = Dart_NewStringFromCString(lpString);

  Dart_SetReturnValue(arguments, result);
  Dart_ExitScope();
}
```

and i added function lookup function list

```
 {"GetActiveWindowString", GetActiveWindowString},
```

when loading the dartapp I get the correct active window.

But while running, the program will only print the value initialized at start. Not the actual active window.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `activeWindow` is marked as [`final`](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-final-const): `A final variable can be set only once;` This means that it doesn't change after it is initialized, and it is initialized at the beginning with value of `getActiveWindowString()` at *that* moment.

Try this:

```
static String get activeWindow => _getActiveWindowString();
```

`activeWindow` is now a property which returns active window at the time of call.

EDIT:

There is a bug in `_getActiveWindowString` implementation:

```
LPTSTR lpString; // lpString is not initialized and points to random location
...
GetWindowText(hwnd, lpString, 128); // overrides the random location
```

It should be:

```
TCHAR lpString[128];
```

Comment: oooooooohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh ooooooooooooooohhhhhhhhhhhh nooooo :D damn it! copy and paste without thinking.. when you mentioned final, I was just like..REALLY.. where?? Deam it. I knew it was something simple.. Thank you!!! 
:D and big shame on me :D:D:D:D 

 **Thank you !!!**

Comment: hmm still seems to be something wrong
Do I additionally need to change something in the cc file? 

and what is the difference between

`static String activeWindow = _getActiveWindowString();`  
and 
`static String get activeWindow => _getActiveWindowString();`  
when using the get way my program crashes the second time it tries to call activeWindow. .. I clicked debug dart.exe in VS2012 it flashed some stuff but dissapeared again within milliseconds.

When using the line without "get" it has the same effect as if using final

Comment: with `static String activeWindow = _getActiveWindowString();`, `activeWindow` will also be initialized once as if using `final`, but anyone can execute `SysInfo.activeWindow = "whatever";`, which is not possible with final. With get, you get the same behavior as calling ` _getActiveWindowString()` every time. I would debug the implementation of that function - maybe something is wrong with it - perheps `lpString` buffer which is not allocated, but instead pointing to random memory? Try declaring it as `LPTSTR lpString[128];`